# Neutral shows only continuity to hot with breaker on

Tags: electrical, receptacle, neutral

I have a GFCI receptacle that as far as I can tell is the first one from the panel (because nothing else is off in the house when the breaker is off). I have to replace the old outlet.

When the breaker is on, I attach my Klein voltmeter to the hot and neutral and only get a continuity reading (beep) but no voltage (shaking and reading on voltage dial).

If I then test the hot to ground I get voltage (both beep and reading)...

I don't get it...how could this happen? Searched online for a while but can't find an answer :( thanks for any pointers!

UPDATE: I checked the panel and the neutral is firmly attached to the ground bus. However when i disconnected the neutral and hot at the panel (with main breaker off) they did not have continuity with the neutral and hot wirenut together on the receptacle end . I'm wondering if the neutral is then compromised and touching ground somewhere?

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to measure continuity with the power on.

Comment: It's a combination voltage and continuity tester like this:  https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000NBCD1K/ref=cm_sw_r_sms_awd_x_DSx6xbXW5HWBK

Comment: So what's the problem? Receptacle doesn't work?

Comment: It's in the bathroom next to the sink so it has to be GFCI but it won't work due to neutral weirdness... The gfi I'm replacing was very old and malfunctioned

Comment: Sounds like the house or at least that outlet is wired wrong. I have rewired entire houses that had the white as hot and the black as neutral.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I will check out how it is hooked in the panel maybe they switched the neutral and ground.

Comment: Hrm...with the breaker off, and the neutral reconnected to the ground bus, can you measure continuity from neutral to ground?

Comment: Thanks ThreePhase that was a great question and no, there's no continuity between neutral and ground with breaker off...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel any thoughts?

Comment: Disconnect neutral and ground at the panel with that circuit's breaker off, and see if they have continuity to each other.